# What does ItemId refer to within a Bill line item

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Bill docs: http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0400_QuickBooks_Online/Bill

I'm getting confusing errors back and trying to figure out what kind of item the ItemId refers to within a line item. Once I specify the amount on a line item it requires the ItemId to be specified but I'm not really sure what type of object it's looking for.

Does anyone know what type of ItemId is expected? Also, is there a list of the constants that are referenced in the documentation too? "SHIPPING_LINE_ID" and "DEPOSIT_LINE_ID" are both mentioned in description column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick,
It's an item object in QBO http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0400_QuickBooks_Online/Item

You reference the item that you are creating a bill for. If the item doesnt exist, you would need to create it first, then create a bill that references it.

thanks
Jarred

Comment: Do we supply the unit price on both bill and item then? Or if we have referenced an item can we rely on it grabbing the unit price from that item?

Comment: I ended up just using an account based bill which actually works better. When you supply quantity or unit price it's assuming it's an item based bill, just supplying amount gets your the more relevant errors that pertain to an account based bill.